# p5.js Getting image from webcam

Tags: p5.js

I made an image processing program where I process an image from my disk.
Now instead of using an image from my disk, I want to use an image from my webcam.

Currently my code is:

```
var img;
let capture;

function preload() {
  img = loadImage('file.jpg');
}

function setup(){
  capture = createCapture(VIDEO);
  // new code, something like img = image(capture); ?
}

// my image processing code using img
...
```

Now, how can I fill `img` with an image file from my webcam video capture instead of file.jpg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the [copy()](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Image/copy) function:

```
let img;
let capture;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  capture = createCapture(VIDEO);
  capture.hide();
  // wait until the video starts playing to create the image
  capture.elt.addEventListener('playing', mousePressed);
  
  noLoop();
}

function draw() {
  if (img) {
    image(img, 0, 0);
  }
}

function mousePressed() {
  // The capture element is initially smaller than it should be
  if (!img || img.width !== capture.width) {
    img = createImage(capture.width, capture.height);
  }
  img.copy(capture, 0, 0, capture.width, capture.height, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
  redraw();
}
```